# Square Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Are the following two statements both true? (maybe there is some small exception to one of them?)

A) Let f, g be real-valued functions. Then, the following is true for all such functions: $$f^2(x)<g^2(x) \Leftrightarrow \left| f(x) \right| < \left| g(x) \right|$$ for all $x\in D_f\cap D_g$

B) For all real numbers x, y it is true that: $$x^2<y^2 \Leftrightarrow |x|<|y|$$

Comment: No exceptions. But perhaps you should try proving it.  Note the first implies the second so just prove for functions.

Comment: Yes, both are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to look at different cases: you just have to use a pair of simple facts:

- $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$,
- $\sqrt{{}\cdot{}}\;$ and $\lvert{}\cdot{}\rvert$ are increasing functions on $\mathbf R_+$.

Thus:

$1)$ $f^2(x)<g^2(x)\implies  \sqrt{f^2(x)}=\lvert f(x)\rvert<\sqrt{g^2(x)}=\lvert g(x)\rvert$.

Conversely, $\;\lvert f(x)\rvert<\lvert g(x)\rvert\implies \bigl(\sqrt{f^2(x)}\bigr)^2=\bigl( f(x)\bigr)^2<\bigl(\sqrt{g^2(x)}\bigr)^2=\bigl(g(x)\bigr)^2$

$2)$ Same argument.

Comment: I just thought that if for a function f $f^2(x)=\sin^2x$ holds then we don't have only two possible functions f but infinite...

Comment: ?? I don't see why. Aren't you confusing with solving equations in $x$ of the form: $\;\sin x =\sin\alpha$?

Comment: There are infinite functions for which $f^2(x)=\sin^2x$ holds. For example, the function: $$f_1(x)=
\begin{cases}
-\sin x,                  & \text{$x<-e^2$} \\
\left| \sin x \right|,  & \text{$x\geq -e^2$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: That's true, but doesn't contradict the fact that they all have the same absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

For B, look at the different cases:
1) if a and b are both positive then a^2< b^2 implies a< b so |a|< |b|. 
2) if a is negative and b positive, then a^2< b^2 implies -a< b so |a|< |b|.
3) if a and b are both negative, then a^2< b^2 implies -a> -b so that |a|< |b|.

And A is implied by B.

Comment: A is not implied by B, since a function can change its sign infinite many times, so it is **not** $f(x)>0 \lor f(x)<0 \lor f(x)=0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.